# Does anyone know where the RemitAddress view is in the VendorMaint BLC?

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to update the Vendor's Remit Address values from inside the BLC - but I can't find the view "RemitAddress" associated with those fields.  I have a graph extension "VendorMaintExt", and I'm trying to use the syntax:

```
var remitaddress = Base.RemitAddress.Current;
```

But Base doesn't have a RemitAddress view showing in the intellisense in Visual Studio.

Where would I find this view so I can update the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Acumatica 2022 version the remit address view is named `RemitAddress` in the `DefLocationExt` graph extension

```
vendorMaintInst.GetExtension<VendorMaint.DefLocationExt>().RemitAddress
```

Comment: That's not there either.

Comment: I've updated the answer to how you can get the `RemitAddress`